# How to Response When New Data is Available?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am doing chat project. i send an AJAX request to server to receive new data every 2 second but in most cases does not exist any new data on server.
i want to response new data when new data is available. in other words i don't want to repeat request every 2 second.
how can i response to client when new data is available?

Comment: What you are looking for is called persistent connections/long polling, SignalR is great for this as @scartag mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have implemented so far but you might want to take a look at Asp.net [SignalR](http://signalr.net) a new addition to the asp.net family.
I think it is better suited for what you are trying to achieve.